# How to access variable of custom control

Tags: javascript, xpages, custom-controls

I am using a custom control on an Xpage. Within this custom control I create JavaScript object.
Later I want to use a function of this JavaScript object. My problem right now is that I can not access this JavaScript Object from my Xpage.
Therefore my question is: Is there any way to pass this instance to my Xpage?

Comment: Can you share some example code?

Comment: You could use the viewScope to store JavaScript object, assuming you mean SSJS object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: I defined my JavaObject globally (window.objName = ...). This enables me to access the object on the whole page.